# Fix Markdown/SmartyPants in question titles

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, title

Consider this question:

[is `x-- > 0 && array[x]` well defined behavior in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044466/is-x-0-arrayx-well-defined-behavior-in-c)

Unfortunately, the question title is displayed on SO as:

> is `x— > 0 && array[x]` well defined behavior in c++?

There are two issues here:

1. Less severe, **the backticks are displayed verbatim** and don’t delimit a code span. Not very nice but bearable. On the other hand, MathOverflow has this really nice math mode even in titles – why not also introduce this on SO for code?
2. **The `--` operator is transformed into an em-dash.** This is slightly misleading and simply unnecessary. I am all in favour of using SmartyPants (or whatever SO uses) to glam up the question title typography. But this shouldn’t go at the cost of correctness.

So I suggest allowing limited Markdown in titles (e.g. as in comments?) or at least fixing the formatting bug.

Comment: "So I suggest allowing limited Markdown in titles (e.g. as in comments?)" - Agreed

Comment: Now I'm wondering if I can add em-dash as an alias for the decrement operator in C...

Comment: Probably worth noting that a search for the title as-written still finds the question. The double-dash is converted to an em-dash during rendering, just as the double-ampersand is converted to &amp;&amp; - it affects the final display (and *possibly* Google indexing) but not the internal title.

Comment: +1 because I wanted to italicize a metasyntactic variable on English.SE in a title... and status-declined, schmatus-declined: even gods can change their minds, so there's hope ;-)

Comment: “Slightly” misleading ? It is totally wrong ! Give that garbage to a C++ compiler, you will see.

Comment: How about providing an escape way ?

Comment: The question title should be "-- -> —, yes or no?"

Comment: … for those of us keeping track: More than eight years and ~ 10 duplicate bug reports later, this is still not fixed.

Comment: _11 years later_: It's fixed now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We have now disabled all [Smarty](https://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/)-like modifications text in titles.

From now on, the title text saved for the post is the title text that will be displayed.

If folks want em-dashes (`ALT-0151`) and fancy quotes (`ALT-0145` through `-0148`) to appear in titles, they are welcome to add them. But we won’t convert it automatically any longer.

That said, we have no plans to introduce markdown in titles.

> we’re no longer the
> smarty-pants who makes changes
> to typography

Comment: Is there some kind of badge for fixing an 11-year-old bug report? Supreme necromancer?

Comment: A bottle of [Smartypants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuCWl.jpg) for you.

Comment: For historical reference, this fix caused an XSS vulnerability: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411177/adding-html-tags-or-html-tag-like-to-a-title-breaks-rendering

Answer (score 28):

I'm not sure we want markdown in titles. However, I think -- -> — is not appropriate for a programming site.

Answer (score 13):

Even given the current MarkDown support in comments (bold, italic, code, links), the only one of those I would want to have in the question titles is code.

I think, given that SO is a programming site, code is reasonable to allow in titles. Regardless of whether or not this would carry a fixed-width style of some kind, it should disable any character transforms such as -- being converted to an em-dash.

Answer (score -7):

We definitely don't want Markdown in question titles

- it's too processing intensive
- it's additional complexity and overkill IMO

And how do we tell the difference between these two titles:

> How do I "accept" an answer-- where do I click?

and

> is x-- > 0 && array[x] well defined behavior in c++?

Comment: So you are going to leave the functionality that converts `--` to `—`?

Comment: Neither of those titles contain code -- auto-code-interpretation is way too much. Allow it within backquotes and that's it.

Comment: trivial: there is no difference. Let the users be explicit: only filter out backtick-delimited sections. This should be straightforward (and is already done for `$…$` on other SE sites).

Comment: Or give us another delimiter to use in titles besides backtick?

Comment: What is `$...$`?

Comment: Markdown in titles too processor-intensive? We just need a backtick in the titles to delimit code - it's trivial to implement! And I'm sure it's not processor intensive, it can't be.

Comment: @Camilo, indeed, if it's processor intensive, then do it in Javascript like SO already does in the preview window.  "Performance" is a canard.

Comment: You force the user to type `How do I "accept" an answer -- where do I click?`, with an extra space, as suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193574/147400)

Comment: How do we tell the difference ? By thinking. With a human brain.

Comment: You can't tell. So don't substitute characters. If the author uses a hyphen, show a hyphen. If the author uses an em dash, show an em dash. If the author uses a ☂, show a ☂.

Comment: @PaulDraper Do you mean "*If the author uses a ☂, show a ☂,*"