# Render code strings in question titles

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, title

It would be nice if backticked code in question titles were rendered the same way they are in question bodies. Since there are so many questions with code in them I feel it would be a big plus. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800698/what-is-the-difference-between-raise-foo-and-raise-exception-newfoo).

This would look a lot nicer in listings and on the page itself if the code strings were rendered as such.

Similar ideas discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68844/fix-markdown-smartypants-in-question-titles).

Comment: I wondered whether it's disadvantageous, e.g. for SEO reasons or any other, to have inline elements within the heading; but no, I see that [phrasing content (for example, `<code>`) is explicitly permitted](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/h1.html#h1-content-model).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fix Markdown/SmartyPants in question titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68844/fix-markdown-smartypants-in-question-titles)

Comment: it wouldn't be transformed at all in the <title>, only in the h1 and question listings

Comment: the question Yi Jiang linked has nothing to do with HTML `title` tags. The first suggestion there is, in fact, an exact duplicate of what you're asking for.

Comment: Hm, you're right. Not sure what I was thinking the first time I looked at it.

Answer (score 5):

It may just be me, but in my opinion, good (great?) question titles shouldn't contain code snippets.  Your question title here, for example, fits my definition of a relatively good title:  concise, the question actually matches the title, good keywords for searching...  Code snippets would have too many of the common language keywords, in this case:  {raise, new, Exception} (not to mention the ubiquitous foo) for good search results.  I'm not sure that having code snippets in titles is something to encourage.

Comment: In all fairness, I'm not sure what I would retitle your linked post as, though :)P

Comment: There are lots of great questions that are *about* a particular keyword or snippet of code. You're saying we should discourage saying what the question is about in the title?

Comment: You wrote "code snippets".  How about programming language keywords, `final`, `volatile`, `Object` or common C++ template parameters, e.g., `Compare`, `begin`, `end`?