# Not rendering ` *` in comments or titles

Tags: bug, comments, markdown

It renders correctly in posts ( `*`), but not above or below.

[image: Screenshot of this post]

Comment: For example: ` *`

Comment: Isn't it a [status-bydesign]?

Comment: Other `code` strings work

Comment: Eh, maybe......

Comment: It never worked in titles though

Comment: I think it's the spaces: ` code `

Comment: @Laurel I was about to post that, but it doesn't explain why it works in posts and not comments.

Comment: @KodosJohnson [Comments use a different Markdown "mini" parser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105316/my-comment-code-block-was-not-converted-properly-is-this-a-bug#comment269934_105316)

Comment: @KodosJohnson Comments use “mini-markdown”, which isn’t the same as what’s used in posts. Titles aren’t formatted at all, which is why it doesn’t work there, making this also a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76439/323179