# Don't change double-hyphens in titles into dashes. At least not on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, title, code

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Fix Markdown/SmartyPants in question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68844/fix-markdown-smartypants-in-question-titles)

This question: [Why is `x-- > 0` not undefined behaviour, while `x = x--` is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924376/why-is-x-0-not-undefined-behaviour-while-x-x-is)

Actually, the `--` in the title of the question is an operator (in code), not a dash. The system should not change it into that, at least not on programming-related sites like Stack Overflow.

Comment: Huh, I knew that duplicate existed but I somehow couldn't find it. No wonder - it never even mentions "double" or "hyphen" or "dash" (aside from em-dash).