# Why is conversion of hyphens to dashes in question titles inconsistent?

Tags: support, markdown, title

There have been questions before about the fact that SE sites automatically convert double-hyphens (e.g. `--`) in question titles into em-dashes (e.g. `—`):

- [Don't change double-hyphens in titles into dashes. At least not on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78390/)
- [Fix Markdown/SmartyPants in question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68844/)

I want to know why the conversion is inconsistent, as seen here:

[image: an HTML-style comment has its first pair of hyphens converted into a dash, but not its second pair]

Is this a glitch? Is there some logic behind when the conversion is made and when it isn't? Are there use cases? This just seems odd to me.

Comment: I *want* to retag this [support] instead of discussion, since I'm not really sure what you're trying to discuss and it seems more like a question of "Why does this behave this way", but I'll hold off for a confirmation out of you for any possible ulterior motive in this question...

Comment: @Grace, ha, I was thinking of using `[support]` when I asked, but I ultimately decided against it because it's not a "how do I use the site" question. I have no ulterior motive, though, and you're welcome to retag.

Answer (score 7):

The conversion from `--` → `—` **requires a whitespace immediately following the hyphens**.

Thus, if it is followed by any character (in your example, `>`), it will be treated as just two hyphens. Note that if you leave it at the very end of the title, there is no whitespace afterwards (unless you *do* add trailing whitespace), so that will also render as two hyphens even with the absense of a character immediately following.

I did testing on Gaming's Formatting Sandbox, and have screenshotted one of the 28 stages of the test below.

[image: Example of hyphens in titles]

No, I don't know how a zero-width non-joiner will affect it, nor any other non-displaying character. But I imagine that'd be the first step to look at for gaming the title to not render it as a dash.

Comment: That is some first water research right there. Have an upvote. Doesn't answer the "why," though.

Comment: @Popular It answers the "why" of "Why does it show two hyphens sometimes, and dashes other times?", just not the "why" of "Why does it require a whitespace?". ♪ The latter of which I assume is mostly because that's how many systems implement auto-correct or auto-formatting. In essence, it behaves not unlike most Markdown formatting which requires a whitespace (or certain valid punctuation, which I've proven to be non-functional for this particular scenario).

Comment: True, but my goal was to find out why the team chose the algorithm they did. You've described the algorithm admirably, but not the thought process behind why they chose it and not some other logic.

Comment: It is interesting that no whitespace _before_ the `--` is required; strange asymmetry.

Comment: @Hendrik I imagine it in part deals with how some people treat the dash in the same way we use a colon: it comes immediately after the last word, but is separated from its denoted context by a space. It's not proper syntax for the dash, but people do it all the same.

Comment: @Grace: Wow-- people really _do_ that? Crazy! But if they do, one shouldn't also _encourage_ them, should one? `:-)`