# Do not replace two hyphens with em dash

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, title

I'm not sure if this is a feature request or a bug report.

Example: [Alternative to git ls-tree -r HEAD -- . :!foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470210/alternative-to-git-ls-tree-r-head-foo)

Before saving, the title appears as two hyphens.

[[image: titleimage--]

After saving, the title remains as two hyphens.

When I refresh the page, an em dash has appeared instead.

[image]

This is poor for readability and for SEO (maybe?).

Ideally, an em dash would be an em dash, and two hyphens would be two hyphens.