# Disable Smarty-like formatting in titles

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, title, code

I tried editing a [recent Stack Overflow post with an em-dash in the title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35035399/is-there-a-git-option-to-force-the-usage-of-dash-dash-for-file-paths). When I tried to fix it, I discovered the post actually contained two *hyphen-minus* (-) characters in the first place – and that these were being converted to an *em-dash* (—) character for displaying the question.

It seems that these issues are due to [titles using a stripped-down version of Smarty formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34587/smart-quotes-in-parentheses-point-the-wrong-way-example-tst-tst/35141#35141).

This is the same bug reported in [Do not replace two hyphens with em dash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266041/do-not-replace-two-hyphens-with-em-dash) and [Don't change double-hyphens in titles into dashes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78390/dont-change-double-hyphens-in-titles-into-dashes-at-least-not-on-stackoverflow).

This issue was originally [raised back in 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68844/fix-markdown-smartypants-in-question-titles) and the author’s request to allow “limited Markdown in titles” was *declined*.

Since this bug continues to crop up, I’d like to propose a simpler (and less ambiguous) solution: **Disable the Smarty-like formatting in titles** (at least on programming sites such as Stack Overflow).

In the most recent case, the question author clearly intended two *hyphen-minus* (-) characters to be displayed.  If someone actually wants typographic dashes to be displayed, they can compose their question in a good text editor that allows them to explicitly insert UTF-8 characters (FWIW, I use the [ItsAllText](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) Firefox extension with Vim as my editor).

Comment: Apparently, [tag:status-bydesign] : from MSO [Two hyphens get changed to a long dash in titles (— vs -)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278604)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelT I suppose that would mean my suggestion is more a feature request (“requests for a change to an existing feature”) than a bug report; I’ve updated the tags accordingly. I'd like the moderators and/or site developers to re-evaluate this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have now disabled all [Smarty](https://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/)-like modifications text in titles.

From now on, the title text saved for the post is the title text that will be displayed.

If folks want em-dashes (`ALT-0151`) and fancy quotes (`ALT-0145` through `-0148`) to appear in titles, they are welcome to add them. But we won’t convert it automatically any longer.

> we’re no longer the
> smarty-pants who makes changes
> to typography

Answer (score 9):

I am in favor of this, SmartyPants-like formatting is an annoyance.

If people want to write typographically correct characters they should use an input method that supports that on their systems.

I use the X11 compose key, on Windows there is a nice program called WinCompose and alternatives exist on all platforms. (For example on Android I use HackersKeyboard which also has a compose key!).

The SmartyPants formatting is trying to fix a solved problem. Unicode allows us to write everything without any magic replacement.

The one thing Unicode does not solve is code formatting, but we do have markdown for that.

Comment: Great minds think more or less alike, and even at roughly the same time: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326389/344751

Comment: Your proposal is a good compromise, so I have upvoted that as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather prefer to allow Markdown in titles.

As for the example, I think it would make more sense to have double dashes shown as inline code like this `--`. Because in this context, double dashes are essentially code and not text.