# All title typography conversions were removed from all sites today. Were they useful on some sites, or should they stay removed everywhere?

Tags: discussion, title, automatic-edits

For a very long time (since at least 2010, perhaps 2008), the system would make modifications to post titles so that they'd better conform to English style guides:

- When "straight quotes" were being used in post titles, those would be automatically converted into “smart quotes” (different curly characters for the beginning and end).
- When there were 2-3 hyphens (-- or ---) in post titles, those would be converted into em dashes (—).
- When there were three dots (.) in a title, those would be converted into an ellipsis character (…).

Today, as part of a longstanding feature request to remove the second behavior on Stack Overflow, as it was causing problems since 2-3 dashes are proper syntax in many programming languages, **[all of these conversions were removed from all sites, network-wide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411176/2157772)**.

To me, this seems like a heavy-handed measure to solve a single concern on a single site (albeit the highest-traffic site). I can imagine that these conversions would have been useful on some other sites such as possibly English Language & Usage, and maybe some other smaller sites. It also breaks posts that depended on this behavior; as the change is retroactive, any posts where it was important will now have to be edited to have those characters explicitly.

As such, I'd like to open this as a general discussion for the network: are these title edits useful on specific sites enough that all or some of them should be reinstated on them, or should it stay network-wide? (My point of view is neutral.)

I found [this prior feature request asking for them to be disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273730/377214), but that post only talks about technical sites, and states that they're OK with having it implemented only on the technical sites. This post talks about all sites.

Comment: I imagine if it had been important to any of those questions, those questions would have already used those characters directly instead of relying on them being replaced...

Comment: @animuson Not everyone would go through the effort to copy and paste those characters from elsewhere. Plus, what I'd once do is put straight quotes in the title and copy paste them from the editor preview.

Comment: But an extreme edge case. This feature wasn't advertised, though, and a user asking a question would be far more likely to copy paste the character they needed into the title than to somehow figure out that there was something else they could do to make it appear. If there are posts negatively affected by disabling it, I'd guess that number is in the single or double digits.

Comment: I don't understand why someone would think a website displaying something other than what I typed into it according to its particular whims is a feature and not a bug. I guarantee you I can type things that will look like ass when some automated system attempts to be "smart". Of what particular benefit are these conversions other than some people like how they look? It seems like it would be hard to know if I should search for `word…` instead of `word...` or `word”` instead of `word"` because I don't know what is actually stored in the title.

Comment: It could potentially override the user's system settings - If I specifically tell my computer "Don't convert to smart characters", then the site converting to smart characters removes my decision to use standard ones. If someone specifically wants smart characters, the user's OS can do that, too.

Comment: @Catija The conversion only happened on display. The actual text saved in the database would be what the user originally typed.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I don't know how that matters. If I specifically want two dashes instead of an emdash, that's something I expressly chose. If I want that to be converted, my system can automate that but if I don't, it should stay the same as it is, even on render.

Comment: Regardless of the merits, changes to the functionality of public Q&A sites should not be made with neither community consultation nor even an announcement. This isn't a bug fix, however you want to look at it.

Comment: @curiousdannii Technically, this change *was* made with community consultation and an announcement (linked in the question). There was a longstanding request to disable bullet 2 on the technical sites. But yes, it should have been restricted to bullet 2 and the technical sites only, not to every site and all bullets.

Comment: Good riddance, I’d say. I never liked these autocorrections where they aren’t configurable and users that do want these could enable this in their OS.

Comment: Just a nitpick--they aren't edits. The characters displayed do not match the characters actually in the title.

Answer (score 7):

On English SE, it looks like the change is mostly superficial.

- Is converting all quotes in the title to smart ones even an improvement? It makes the titles consistent with each other but it usually makes the body inconsistent with the title. You can make an argument for which consistency is more important, but in the end there's some inconsistency.
- Will anyone notice the difference between ... and …? Titles can't be mono spaced so it seems doubtful.
- And hyphens. I looked at all the titles that had -- (or more dashes) in them, and there were only 300 (too many to edit at once but not too many that I would give up on editing them all). For some I would use an em dash instead of dashes, though even without it they're clear (and some of these questions used four dashes so they would have needed to be retyped under the old system anyway). For others, I would remove the dashes entirely in favor of something else (such as underscores for a blank). For yet other questions, having two regular dashes is an improvement: some questions needed two dashes in the title because that's what they were asking about (example: [What is the difference between `-` and `--`](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/9627/191178)).

  - [My query](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/revision/1455356/1786946/): `select score, id as [Post Link] from posts where title like '%--%' order by score desc`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should only have been applied to technical sites, where `--` might have a specific meaning, and where typographers' quotes could cause problems.

On non-technical sites, *particularly* language sites and/or those with a site-specific font stack, this change is unnecessary, potentially counterproductive (again because "--" does not mean "—" and it's far more likely that "—" is actually intended) and **simply ugly.** On non-technical sites this is change for the sake of change.

This objection might have been raised on the original question had that not suggested actually making a distinction.

And it's taken **over five years** for that request to be implemented. At the very least that should have resulted in an "Is this still required?" question with a "This is what we propose to do" section.

Comment: One person’s ugly is another’s exactly-as-I-intended-it. This doesn’t prevent people from putting em dashes in their titles and it allows people who want double dashes to have them display as written.

Comment: @colleenv While that's true, it's arguable that it has only just become intended, and some consultation on how people's intentions marry up would certainly have been welcome. I care about the site I care for, and I'm increasingly tired of detrimental changes.

Comment: It is in general a bad idea for a computer to force its interpretation of what someone intended on them with no possibility of correcting it, which is exactly what this feature did. If I really want to have a double dash in my title on EL&U, I should be allowed to have it. It's bad to have different text displayed than the text that is actually in the title, especially when it's difficult to tell whether someone intentionally put an em dash in, or if the title really has two hyphens. I miss EL&U's old theme too, but this change is about  usability more than aesthetics.

Comment: There is perhaps evidence of adverse effect in only one title, and that could be edited to be fixed. It's bad practice to change things when there is no reason to do so, and even worse to do so on the basis of a five-year-old request for something different.

Comment: How do you edit the title to display two hyphens? The text in the title isn't being replaced, it is being dynamically interpreted and displaying something other than the characters actually in the title. How do you know what to search for if you can't see what characters are actually in the title? Just because it wasn't broke for you doesn't mean there's no reason to change it. I've stated multiple reasons it should have never been implemented that way in the first place.

Comment: But it was implemented, and without adverse effect on non-technical sites. Change should always be minimal. Of course, I can't test a demo of how to edit the title, because the behaviour has changed.

Comment: It does have an adverse effect, you just don't believe that the impact is significant because you like the way it behaves. There was no way to put "--" in a title. There was no way to correct the display of quotes if the computer guessed incorrectly short of inserting unicode characters that make searches more difficult. The principle of the thing is wrong. I should be able to see the text as typed by its author, not a context insensitive computer interpretation of it. It's not correct to substitute an em dash when someone uses hyphens to indicate a blank to be filled in, for example.

Comment: Well, there you go. In that instance, it's absolutely correct to substitute a dash for hyphens.

Comment: No, it's not correct to display "——-" when I type "-----". Regardless, it's apparent there's little left to say that would be productive at this point.