# Footer has shifted to the side of the screen instead of the bottom

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, footer

While researching how to make CSS image height by width, I came across this question on Stack Overflow. At first I thought it was a joke, I think there is a mistake. The footer seems to have shifted to the side.

Question link : [CSS: 100% width or height while keeping aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751565/css-100-width-or-height-while-keeping-aspect-ratio)

**Note**: I did not encounter such a problem in other questions.
[image]

Comment: Cross site dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411177/adding-html-tags-or-html-tag-like-to-a-title-breaks-rendering

Comment: I guess someone let the lid of pandora's boxed that is called snippets?

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL when there is actual risk of stealing user cookies, collecting private data, and overall HUGE security scandal, they're super fast.

Comment: As this is marked status-completed there is no need for this to be closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted by Yaakov Ellis [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411183/208273), the recent [changes to title functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369331/165261) introduced a failure to escape HTML tags in titles, resulting in them breaking the site's layout by introducing unexpected HTML.

The issue has now been fixed by disabling that change, pending a proper fix.